# Excessive number of +1's on Blog posts

Tags: blogger, google-plus-1

On my blog posts on blogger, I have an inordinate amount of +1's (Like 10,117!). As seen here:

[image]

This seems exceedingly odd as this is a private blog that only approved users can read. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: I've seen that too, but only on private blogs.     So I'm thinking that it's most likely a bug in Blogger, and not something to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with private blogs. Google seems to be working (although not that hard I guess) on it.

See:
http://knownissues.blogspot.ca/2013/04/navbar-1-counts-are-displaying.html
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/Gmj9RtHm99s